# How to avoid [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, http

HTTP is stateless connection. I am making 'HTTP Server'(I am very new to programming).

What I want to do is use POST methods to exchange information between browser and python based http server. To make it work I must close socket and open it up again(because of HTTP specification, I understand connection must be completely closed before you can make new connection to server to use GET or POST method, again, I am planning to send big files over POST only, as GET is very limited)

There is mechanism that prevents me to close/open socket using loop. I am not sure if its part of Unix sockets or Python specification. Probably former case.

If I set socket.close()/socket.receive() loop - I get error:
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
How do I solve my dilemma. Apache does this exactly no problem(I understand its in C or C++), but its probably using same sockets library on Unix anyway.(AFAIK python sockets is a wrapper for C or C++ library)

I don't like idea of http.server, because it does not allow for post without 'CGI', which I don't think I need. Also it's pretty badly documented in my opinion.

Tried reading http.server documentation.
Tried to rebind port number of POST method, turned out - not really possible.
Done several hours of googling.

```
while None is None:
    connection, addr = server.accept()
    content_of_connection = connection.recv(1024)
    connection.sendall(some_words.encode())
    connection.sendall(content_of_connection)
    print (content_of_connection.decode())
    server.close()
```

Need to make looping of 'socket.close()' not give error "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use".

Comment: You are not supposed to create a server socket again and again. Instead you just create a server socket once and then do multiple `accept` on it to get a new connection to a client.  *"I don't like idea of http.server, because it does not allow for post without 'CGI', which I don't think I need. Also it's pretty badly documented in my opinion."* - the problem might be more that you are very new to programming and not the bad documentation. And one can do POST without CGI. Try searching for [python3 http.server example post](https://www.google.com/search?q=python3+http.server+example+post).

Comment: I am not going to argue wit point that I may be too inexperienced to read documentation well, however, I will point out, that POST requires CGI - is in actual documentation.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

'do_POST()

    This method serves the 'POST' request type, only allowed for CGI scripts. Error 501, “Can only POST to CGI scripts”, is output when trying to POST to a non-CGI url.'

With that said, i will try to make several 'accepts'  option you suggested. Thank you

Comment: *"...too inexperienced to read documentation..."* - I think you confirm the point yourself in your comment since you are citing from the documentation of the `http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler` subclass not the `http.server` base class.

Comment: Again, as Steffen correctly noticed, I am too green of a rookie to even properly read documentation. I will stay my ground that documentation is very often very confusing.

With that said, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was closing socket instead of closing, i guess, 'session'? changed server close to connection close, and code works, so can go ahead and mess with HTTP protocol POST method. Doesn't look like I will need http.server in my app anyway...

Comment: You've closed a socket but the wrong one. You should have closed the socket `connection` (connection to the client) but instead  you closed the socket `server` (which was listening for new connections from clients). The proper terms are *"connected socket"* and *"server socket"* (or "*listening socket"*). *"session"* is usually used in different contexts.